# Best text extractor for android

Tags: android, text-extraction

I am new to android please tell which framework/library is best to extract the text from image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tesseract library..

Here is the link

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

This will help you.

Comment: Hi Pri i tried that one but while configuring project in android studio many problem comming

Comment: This is the best one. i have used the same. follow the steps properly

Comment: which ide you are using

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759959/including-so-libraries-android-studio-tess-two-tesseract

Comment: For me this error showing                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'textfairy' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: Check the dependencies you have aded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547154/the-project-may-be-using-a-version-of-gradle-that-does-not-contain-the-method-c

Comment: yeah i added dependencies correctly. But same error showing for me. :(